# Nested React State returns Undefined and Undefined on javascript expressions using hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, state

I am working on a react project and when I load data from the state, it loads properly but when I load nested states or apply JS operations, It returns undefined

**Here is the Reducer**

```
export const contributorDetailsReducer = (
  state = { contributor: { contribution: { topUp: [] } } },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, contributor: action.payload };
    case CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_RESET:
      return { contributor: {} };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here is the action

```
export const contributorListDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/customers/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CONTRIBUTOR_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the Screen code snippet

```
const ContributorDetailsScreen = ({ history, match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const contributorDetails = useSelector((state) => state.contributorDetails);
  const { loading, error, contributor } = contributorDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(contributorListDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match]);
  return (
    <>
      <Link className="btn btn-light my-3" to="/all-contributors">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Row>
          <Col className="text-center" md={12}>
            <h1>
              {`${contributor.firstName} ${contributor.lastName} ${
                contributor.otherName || ''
              }`}
            </h1>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
```

Here is the state

```
contributor:
  loading(pin):false
  minor(pin):true
  createdAt(pin):"2020-12-02T14:42:23.140Z"
  _id(pin):"5fc7a826bddf9410360f0caf"
  branch:
    _id(pin):"5fa281e2658a2305c7ffdd76"
    name(pin):"HK Road"
    region(pin): "12"
  firstName(pin):"Emmanuel"
```

[State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjPKT.png)

The above works correctly. But when I try to reach branch.name,

```
<p>contributor.branch.name</p>
```

or I try to modify

```
<p>contributor.firstName.toUpperCase()</p>
```

I get the error

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
ContributorDetailsScreen
src/screens/ContributorDetailsScreen.js:39
  36 | )}
  37 | <Row className="my-3">
  38 |   <Col className="text-center" md={12}>
> 39 |     <h1>
     | ^  40 |       {`${contributor.firstName.toUpperCase()} ${contributor.lastName} ${
  41 |         contributor.otherName || ''
  42 |       }`}{' '}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS4ss.png)

or

```
  26 | ) : (
  27 |   <Row>
  28 |     <Col className="text-center" md={6}>
> 29 |       <h1>{contributor.branch.name}</h1>
     | ^  30 |     </Col>
  31 |     <Col className="text-center" md={6}>
  32 |       <h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you fetching the users (async), you should wait until the value is available before calling `toUpperCase()` on it.

```
<Col className="text-center" md={12}>
  <h1>
    // or contributor.firstName && contributor.firstName.toUpperCase()
    {`${contributor.firstName?.toUpperCase()} ${contributor.lastName} ${
      contributor.otherName || ""
    }`}
  </h1>
</Col>;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I'd Love to be your friend too. If you can send your twitter or linkedin ID for a follow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your default state has loading set as `true`. You seem to set it only when when you start your request, meaning there will be one render where loading will be undefined and your loader will not show. Another option would be to test for undefined:

```
{loading || loading === undefined ? (
    <Loader />
) : (
    <Row>
        <Col className="text-center" md={12}>
            <h1>
                {`${contributor.firstName} ${contributor.lastName} ${
                    contributor.otherName || ''
                }`}
            </h1>
        </Col>
    </Row>
)}
```